# Difference between (args is { Length: > 0}) and args.Length?

Tags: c#, .net, runtime

I was going through some of the code in the dotnet runtime, and I've noticed that instead of writing something like this:

`if (args.Length > 0)`

they use this:

`if (args is { Length: > 0})`

Do you know if there are any advantages of using the second method instead of the first? Seems longer and less easy to read but for some reason, the second method is used?

Comment: Where did you see this code in the runtime?

Comment: It looks like this is in the C#8 proposals, they call it [Property Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#property-pattern) matching

Comment: @DavidG I saw it here: [link](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/01619ed19a7a2073972ee18758227f79ee3b8ba0/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/HostingHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L195)

Comment: @Jonesopolis it's a combination of property patterns `{ Length: ... }` from c#8 and relational patterns `>0`  from C#9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `args` is null, then `args.Length > 0` throws a NullReferenceException.

In the same situation, `args is { Length: > 0}` simply evaluates to `false`.

Comment: I guess you could do this instead: ```args?.Length > 0```?

Comment: You could, but the code maintainers could argue `args is { Length: > 0}` is more readable, or allows for easy addition of more conditions than just Length > 0.